# Flutter: Why the hashCodes of the following container widgets are changing eveytime I hot-reload the app (save the file)?

Tags: flutter, hashcode

If I run the following application and observe the hashCodes for BuildSizedBoxWidget which I create two instances of, I notice that they are the same even when I hot reload the app. Does this mean that they are the same widget but referenced multiple times? ... But in case of BuildContainerWidget the hashCodes change every time I hot reload the app. Why does this happen?

'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApps());
    }
    
    class MyApps extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApps({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          title: 'Test',
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({super.key});
    
      final List<Widget> widgets = const [
        BuildSizedBoxWidget(),
        BuildSizedBoxWidget(),
        BuildContainerWidget(),
        BuildContainerWidget()
      ];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('What is happening'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: widgets,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class BuildSizedBoxWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const BuildSizedBoxWidget({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        const Widget widget = SizedBox(height: 50, child: Text('test'));
        print(widget.hashCode);
        return widget;
      }
    }
    
    class BuildContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const BuildContainerWidget({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Widget widget = Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red);
        print(widget.hashCode);
        return widget;
      }
    }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

- The variables defined in the body of the build method will be re-initialized during SetState.
- Variables specified by the const keyword are not initialized.
- There are only three parameters required by SizeBox Widget, and all of them can be initialized.
  But Container Widget contains many parameters that cannot be initialized. So Container cannot be specified with the const keyword
- If you put them outside the body of the build method, the HasCode will not change

```
class BuildContainerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  BuildContainerWidget({super.key});
  Widget widget = Container(key: Key('value'), height: 50, child: Text('test'));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.hashCode);
    return widget;
  }
}
```